# Show explicitly that A has neither the Heine-Borel property, no the Bolzano-Weierstrass property.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

The set $A$ is not compact in the space $X$. Show explicitly that $A$ has neither the Heine-Borel property, no the Bolzano-Weierstrass property.

a) $A = \{ z: 0 <|z| \leq 1 \}$ , $ X = \mathbb C$ with $d(z,w) = |z-w|$

b) $A = [-1,1]$, $X = \mathbb R $ with $d(x,y) = 1 +|x-y|$ if $x \neq y$, $d(x,x) = 0$

If $A$ has no Bolzano-Weierstrass property then it has no Heine-Borel property either? By explicitly showing means should I prove these sets are not closed nor bounded?(e.g for the second case can I conclude that since $A$ has no limit point and infinite $\implies$ it is not compact so it has no Heine-Borel property?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first set $A$:

- Doesn't have the Heine-Borel property because $A\subset\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}}\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\middle|\,|z|<1-\frac1n\right\}$, but there is no finite subset $F$ of $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ such that $A\subset\bigcup_{n\in F}\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\middle|\,|z|<1-\frac1n\right\}.$
- Doesn't have the Bolzano-Weierstrass property because the sequence $\left(1-\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has no subsequence which converges to an element of $A$.

---

Your second set $A$ is easier:

- It doesn't have the Heine-Borel property because $A\subset\bigcup_{x\in A}\{a\}$. Each $\{a\}$ is an open subset of $A$, since $\{a\}=B_1(a)$. But there is no finite subset $F$ of $A$ (and actually no subset of $A$ distinct form $A$) such that $A\subset\bigcup_{a\in F}\{a\}$.
- For this metric, a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $l$ if and only if $a_n=l$ if $n\gg1$. So, take *any* injective sequence, such has $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Such a sequence can have no convergent subsequence.

Comment: Could you do it for the second case also the distance metric confuses me?

Comment: @Pumpkin Done. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes it is crystal clear thank you very much.

Comment: @Pumpkin I hope you don't mind that I've edited your question.